Contrasts for type III ANOVA on mixed effects model (lme) in R
I'm running a series of mixed effects models using nlme in R. Here is an example of my final model:
M1.Final <- lme(Response ~Treatment * Species, random = ~1|ID, 
         data = data, method="REML")

I ran an initial Type II ANOVA to account for the unbalanced design (range of 9-25 samples per treatment) and got these results:
Anova(M1.Final, type = 2)

                     Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)    
Treatment         152.1071  4  < 2.2e-16 ***
Species             1.9636  1   0.161130    
Treatment:Species  15.2138  4   0.004278 ** 

Because the Treatment:Species interaction is significant, it is my understanding that a Type III ANOVA is warranted instead of a Type II. I know that to run a Type III you have to change the contrasts for the model. I wanted to check and make sure I am doing this correctly. Is it ok to just change the contrasts within the ANOVA command, or do I need to change it within the lme command? i.e. is this correct:
type3 <- list(Treatment = contr.sum, Species = contr.sum)

Final_Anova <- Anova(M1.Final, contrasts = type3, type=3) 
print(Final_Anova)

                         Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)    
    (Intercept)       106.6099  1  < 2.2e-16 ***
    Treatment         151.0898  4  < 2.2e-16 ***
    Species             0.0406  1   0.840396    
    Treatment:Species  15.2138  4   0.004278 ** 


Here is the interaction plot:

UPDATE: It sounds like you are supposed to specify the contrasts within lme. I tried that and got a wonky output so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong:
test <- lme(Response ~Treatment * Species, random = ~1|ID, 
         data = data, method="REML", contrasts = type3)
Anova(test, type = 3)

(Intercept)       1575.8  1  < 2.2e-16 ***
Treatment                 0               
Species                   0               
Treatment:Species         0     


EDIT: It sounds like a type III isn't necessarily warranted if you have a significant interaction. Any insight into how to choose an ANOVA type in this situation would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Type III analyses that include interactions are difficult to interpret.  Usually, an interaction is regarded as the modification of one main effect by another.  In Type II analyses, interactions are adjusted for main effects, but main effects are not adjusted for interactions.  This is consistent with the standard interpretation.  In a Type II analysis, every effect in the model is adjusted for every other.  This is not consistent with the standard interpretation.

Thanks for your comment. Just so I understand, does this mean we can't draw conclusions about the significance of the main effect? I have also run separate models for the two species and found that treatment was highly significant, so I feel confident with that. I can post an image of the interaction plot if that would be helpful

That sort of discussion is out-of-scope for this site. I’d suggest Cross Validated if you want to explore that sort of debate. Also, I think it’s fair to say that  views on the utility of Type III analyses differ depending on what side of the Atlantic you are on.  I’ve just spotted a typo in my first comment. The final Type II should be Type III. Apologies.

Ok, I can re-post on Cross Validated to get a better sense of which type is appropriate. Thanks!

Don't repost the same question, though, if moderators think it's better on that site they'll switch it.

Did you get any warnings when you tried specifying the contrasts within lme? I made up a test data set and am getting warnings.

I did not get any warnings with my dataset

That's odd, I was beginning to think there was a bug in the Anova.lme implementation. But if you didn't get any warnings, perhaps you have something different going on. 1) Try with lme4, that worked for me with my test data. 2) Make a reproducible example so we can all see exactly what you have.

Update: I'm pretty sure there's a bug somewhere, it may actually be in model.matrix as applied to lme objects, but I haven't yet been able to exactly reproduce the issue outside of the car function.

Ok, I will try it with lme4, thank you. I am still curious about the topic of whether a type III is warranted in this case, or if I should go with another type.

The short answer is that the interaction is significant, and so you should almost certainly explore that instead of worrying about tests for main effects.

Ben is correct: This is a bug in Anova.lme(), probably introduced in 2022 when I added a check for missing factor levels. The bug is now fixed in the development version of the car package on R-Forge, which I plan to send to CRAN soon after further testing.
Some more detail: The car package has an unexported model.matrix.lme() method. which didn't pass contrast information to model.matrix.default(), and the latter ignores the contrasts in the "lme" model. I fixed model.matrix.lme() so that it now passes contrast information.
Thank you, Ben, for bringing this bug to my attention.
Some comments unrelated to the bug: As already has been pointed out, one should not switch from type-II to type-III tests after testing for interactions -- the tests will not have their nominal alpha levels. If you're interested in testing main effects in the presence of interactions, which are then effects averaged over the other factor(s) entering into the interaction, you should just do type-III tests in the first place. In my opinion, however, it's almost always the case that main effects are of interest only when interactions are absent, which is why type = 2 is the default in Anova().

Thanks, John! That detail explains why I couldn't reproduce the issue outside of car::Anova, I didn't look for a model.matrix.lme function. Appreciate your quick fix!

I suspect that car::Anova.lme has a bug in it that makes it not handle two-level factors with contr.sum properly. (AFAICT this happens whether or not there is an interaction, and whether we use type=2 or type=3)
tl;dr I'm able to replicate similar weird results to yours with Anova(<lme_fit>, ...) with sum-to-zero contrasts. Otherwise (with an lm or lmer fit, or with treatment contrasts) I get more sensible-looking results (although to be honest I haven't looked at them in great detail).
simulate test case
library(glmmTMB)  ## for simulate_new()
library(car)
library(nlme)
library(lme4)

nt <- 5
ns <- 2
nr <- 10
dd <- expand.grid(treatment=factor(1:nt), species=  factor(1:ns),
                  rep = 1:nr)
dd$ID <- factor(rep(1:(nrow(dd)/5), each = 5))
set.seed(101)
dd$response <- simulate_new(~treatment*species + (1|ID),
                     newdata = dd,
                     newparams = list(beta = rnorm(nt*ns),
                                      theta = 1,
                                      betadisp = 0),
                     family = gaussian)[[1]]

lm fits
m1 <- lm(response ~ treatment*species, data = dd)
Anova(m1, type = 2)
cc <- list(treatment = contr.sum, species = contr.sum)
m1C <- update(m1, contrasts = cc)
Anova(m1C, type = 3)

lme fits
m2 <- lme(response ~ treatment*species, random = ~1|ID, data = dd)
Anova(m2, type = 3)
m2C <- update(m2, contrasts = cc, method = "REML")
Anova(m2C, type = 3)

With sum-to-zero contrasts I get this:
Response: response
                   Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)    
(Intercept)        0.211  1      0.646    
treatment         28.300  3  3.142e-06 ***
species                   0               
treatment:species         0               

and

Warning message:
In Anova.III.lme(mod, vcov., singular.ok = singular.ok) :
The following coefficients are not in the model due to missing levels:
treatment5, species2, treatment2:species2, treatment3:species2, treatment4:species2, treatment5:species2

I think this may have to with the different naming of the coefficients when sum-to-zero contrasts are used ...
> names(fixef(m2))
 [1] "(Intercept)"         "treatment2"          "treatment3"         
 [4] "treatment4"          "treatment5"          "species2"           
 [7] "treatment2:species2" "treatment3:species2" "treatment4:species2"
[10] "treatment5:species2"
> names(fixef(m2C))
 [1] "(Intercept)"         "treatment1"          "treatment2"         
 [4] "treatment3"          "treatment4"          "species1"           
 [7] "treatment1:species1" "treatment2:species1" "treatment3:species1"
[10] "treatment4:species1"

try an additive model
m2A <- lme(response ~ treatment+species, random = ~1|ID, data = dd)
Anova(m2A, type = 3)
m2AC <- update(m2, contrasts = cc)
Anova(m2AC, type = 3) ## also weird

lmer fits
m3 <- lmer(response ~ treatment*species + (1|ID), data = dd)
Anova(m3, type = 3)
m3C <- update(m3, contrasts = cc)
Anova(m3C, type = 3)

These look fine, at least superficially.

No, you need to change it in the lme command. I don't think there's a contrasts argument to the car::Anova function; it's not listed in the help page, anyway. There is an icontrasts, but that's something different.
Plus, when rerunning the first example in the help page with contrasts as an argument to Anova instead of as an argument to lm, the results are no different from including no contrast term.
mod2 <- lm(conformity ~ fcategory*partner.status, data=Moore)
Anova(mod2, type=3)
type3 <- list(list(fcategory=contr.sum, partner.status=contr.sum))
Anova(mod2, type=3, contrasts=type3) 

That said, you don't need to switch to Type III just because the interaction is significant. Type II and Type III answer different scientific questions, and you should make your choice accordingly, not based on a p-value.
But as was mentioned, that's a discussion to have on Crossvalidated.

I was just looking on Crossvalidated for a good post to link to and there's a bunch of questions about this, and they don't link up well with each other, nor is there one good authoritative answer (IMHO).

Russ Lenth (author of emmeans) commented once that "Type 2 tests are based on model reduction tests (comparing a full and reduced model), whereas type 3 are based on estimable contrasts" which I think is the most useful way to understand it, rather than trying to understand Type III as "adjusting for interactions" which really isn't meaningful unless you already understand the mathematics.

Hmm, ok, I tried adding contrasts to the lme command and got a super wonky output. I'll update my question with those results.
